# Designing a C# server for handling platform independent data?

Tags: c#, sockets, cross-platform, request

I am looking into designing an application that can run on multiple platforms (i.e. windows, macintosh, android, iphone) but which all interact with data stored and processed on one central server.

Basically:
The server hosts state of world - including active clients, their entity within the world, and rules for rendering the world from the perspective of that entity.
Clients hold a reference to that entity and send requests to the server to update its state and retrieve the renderings based on their entity.

My strongest language above all is C# so I would prefer to write the server using that.

I know that I will need to develop my own sort of command syntax that can be be interpreted by the server and be universal to all clients. What I don't know is much of anything about the practical implementation of coding the server, just the high-level idea of what is necessary.

Is the .Net sockets API usable with non-.Net socket clients? Is that even a valid question?

Basically I would like to know how best to send and receive data in a structured way, but a way that is independent of platform.

A sample of the data needed for a request would be something like

Entity: [Entity Name]
RequestType: [Request Type] (Lets say its an action command)
ActionType: [Action Type]
ActionProp1: [Action Property]
.
.

or

Entity: [Entity Name]
RequestType: [Request Type] (Lets say request render)
RenderDimX: [X Dimension of Render]
RenderDimY: [Y Dimension of Render]

I haven't actually planned out the request syntax yet, so don't criticize :)

This is just the kind of message I want to be sending from client to server.

So how do I set up a C# server to handle clients that will be sending these types of messages? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using sockets. The standardized protocols made it fairly easy.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do REST based services and have everything available through those?  Served up as HTML / XML / etc., any client should be able to connect, query, and use the data sent back.  Programming at the socket level seems a bit much for what sounds like a software as a service model.

Comment: The images will be generated in memory as a byte[] and never persisted to the file system, does this affect anything with REST?

Comment: Essentially the server's initial state is determined by some set resources, but from that point onwards everything is stored in memory. The goal is to have it set up as an ad-hoc or on-the-fly server for only one instance. (If that changes anything)

Comment: I believe you can serialize images and provide them as base-64 encoded strings.  You'll reach upper limits on the default message size, so pay attention to that in the web.config.  It is easy enough to change and the error that is thrown because of it says plain and simple that the file size needs increasing.

Comment: The main issue with REST is that the majority of users aren't going to be running IIS/Apache/etc and won't have the capability to. The goal would be to have this be lightweight and have as few dependencies as possible.

Comment: I'm confused.  The server application is the only one needing a service endpoint.  All client applications will just need URLs to the server.  Or are you talking about designing the server that anyone can run?

Comment: Anyone should be able to host the server on their PC without installing IIS. Anyone should be able to connect to the server from any device. As a simple example, the server hosts a poker game, you want anyone with a PC to be able to host the game for anyone with any device. But you don't want to install a web service or IIS to host a poker game, you just want to click 'Host game' and have it available only when you want.

Comment: In that case, I don't think you can accomplish what you want with .NET.  It will not run on all the devices you are planning.  It would work if you were designing the server, but since this is meant to run on all devices, I think you'll have to go the route of designing the software specifically for each device, but sockets programming is the eventual path I think you'll take.  It will just be up to the hosting operating system to dictate how you will access that API.

Comment: Sorry, the application will run on all devices and will have device specific implementations, the server will only run on Windows and handle interactions from all implementations of the application.

Comment: So then just make the server REST-based and have all the client applications use REST queries to get / set data.  They don't need to run the server.  All operating systems have the capabilities to do REST based queries, so then you wouldn't need to do sockets programming.

Comment: You are missing the point where I do not want the individual running the server to be required to host an application server be it IIS or otherwise. If someone downloads a phone application and its desktop counterpart which allows them to host games for friends, they don't want to configure their desktop to be an application server. They just want to click one button that starts the server, and when it closes, the server is gone. They don't want to find their windows install disk to install IIS to host their game-server's REST API.